# How to overwrite a value for a key in scripting.dictionary?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following if clause nested inside a for loop:

```
    If status Like "*Active*" Then
        total_active = total_active + amount
        On Error Resume Next
        active_dict.Add Key:=cost_center, Item:=total_active
        On Error GoTo 0
    end if
```

`On Error Resume Next` is for ignoring the error when a key that already exists in `active_dict` dictionary is being added to it.

The problem is the value (`total_active`) for the key (`cost_center`) does not get updated.

Question is: is it possible to overwrite a value for a dictionary key?

Comment: `active_dict(cost_center) = total_active`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the Microsoft Scripting Dictionary, you can use the following:

```
If status Like "*Active*" Then
    total_active = total_active + amount
    If active_dict.Exists(cost_center) Then
        active_dict(cost_center) = total_active
    Else
        active_dict.Add Key:=cost_center, Item:=total_active
    End If
End If
```

or even better (see Kostas K comment):

```
If status Like "*Active*" Then
    total_active = total_active + amount
    active_dict(cost_center) = total_active
End If
```

Comment: FYI, no need to check if a Key exists. it will be added anyway if not, once you reference it (as shown in your comment). :)

Comment: I don't use often Dictionary, I didn't know that.